# I'm trying to compare a single image to a MySQL table of 2M+ images, what is a good way to show top 100 matches?

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing, hash, comparison

What I have managed so far: (These are done)

1. A MySQL table which stores the details of 2M+ images.
2. I have computed the phash of each image and stored it in a field in the same table.
3. Compute the phash of a new image during insert.
4. Comparison of two phash's for similarity / difference. (phash distance)

What I need to do further:

1. Take a new image's phash and compare it to the entire table one at a time.
2. Display the 100 most similar images on the screen.

(similar to images.google.com search, but only using phash).

My issues:

I can easily compare 1 image has to every hash stored, but that will generate 2M+ phash distances, which then have to be ordered and then only the top 100 need to be displayed.

Options:
 1. Create a view table in mysql and store all distances in that table.

```
- concurrent users will generate huge number of comparisons and I will run out of memory.
```

2. Use php to do an insert sort into an array of 100 elements and then remove the last element every time a smaller distance is found, then update my 'threshhold' value to the 100th element so that I reduce the number of values needed to be inserted over time.

Comment: How big is a single pHash? Surely you are not calculating the pHash distances in SQL? Have you considered parallelising/multithreading it to calculate 500,000 pHash distances on each of say 4 CPUs?